# Downloading images using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to download images from a website like so:

```
        List <WebElement> listofItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.heroThumbnails:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(n)"));
    URL imageURL = null;
    for(WebElement myElement : listofItems) {
        String j = myElement.getAttribute("data-bigurl");
        System.out.println(j);
        for(int i = 0; i < listofItems.size(); i++){
            try {
                //generate url
                imageURL = new URL(j);
                int countF = 0;
                //read url and retrieve image
                BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);

                //download image to the workspace where the project is, save picture as picture.png (can be changed)
                ImageIO.write(saveImage, "jpg", new File(countF++ + ".jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

When the picture is saved, it is overwriting the previous one. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could help :

```
ImageIO.write(saveImage, "jpg", new File(i + ".jpg"));
```

I guess you overwrite because you give them the same name.

So you could use loop counter (the line at the top) or just declare your `countF` outside:

```
int countF = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < listofItems.size(); i++) {
    try {
        // all your stuff here
        // ...

        // this will create an image with new name each time
        ImageIO.write(saveImage, "jpg", new File(countF + ".jpg"));
        countF++;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `countF` variable outside your loop so its value is preserved between images.

```
    int countF = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < listofItems.size(); i++){
        try {
            //generate url
            imageURL = new URL(j);
            //read url and retrieve image
            BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);

            //download image to the workspace where the project is, save picture as picture.png (can be changed)
            ImageIO.write(saveImage, "jpg", new File(countF++ + ".jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Unrelated: this code is a bit subject `new File(countF++ + ".jpg"));` I personally dont like `countFF++ + ".jpg"` Theres too many `+` in a row for my liking and incrementing inline. I would prefer:

```
countF++;
new File(countF + ".jpg"));
```

but thats just my personal style, both should work.